# Kivy: Why isn't ScrollView working inside GridLayout?

Tags: python, kivy

I have a GridLayout inside of a ScrollView and for some reason, I cannot scroll the GridLayout. I initially used a BoxLayout but saw from another answer that it was better to use a GridLayout.

kv:

```
<ScreenTwo>
    id: screen_two
    name: "two"
    on_leave: app.restart()
    on_enter: app.display_btn()

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        rows: 1
        ScrollView:
            do_scroll_x: False
            do_scroll_y: True
            GridLayout:
                cols: 1
                id: streak_zone
                height: self.minimum_height
...
```

Comment: Have a look at the [https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html#managing-the-content-size-and-position].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## GridLayout

You need to add the following so that it can scroll when the widgets / buttons added have exceeded the `ScrollView`'s height.

- Add `size_hint_y: None`
- Add `row_force_default: True`
- Add `row_default_height: 40`

### Snippets - kv file

```
    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_x: False
        do_scroll_y: True

        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            id: streak_zone
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            row_force_default: True
            row_default_height: 40    # Change the height to fit your specs
```